# Parameters of a lognormal distribution

Tags: statistics

I've been given the mean and standard deviation of a lognormal distribution and asked to find the parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$ for this distribution, but I'm not sure how to convert to a normal distribution.

I've seen on some sources that
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\mu &=& \log\left( \dfrac{m^2}{\sqrt{v+m^2}} \right) \\
\sigma &=& \sqrt{\log\left( \dfrac{v}{m^2} + 1 \right)}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

where $m$ = mean and $v$ = variance.

I am not sure how they arrived at these 2 equations.

Answer (score 2):

A lognormal distributed random variable $X$ means its logarithm $Y=\ln X$ is normally distributed. Therefore $X=e^Y$. Since the exponential function is convex (with positive second-order derivative everywhere), the mean $\langle X\rangle>e^{\langle Y\rangle}$. That's why if $Y\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, the mean of $X$ is not simply $e^\mu$. Now let's work out the mean and variance of $X$. We have

$$\langle X^n\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}e^{ny}dy=e^{\mu n+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}n^2}.$$

We can calculate this integral by completing the square in the exponent to obtain the mean $\langle X\rangle$ by setting $n=1$ and the variance $\mathrm{var}(X)=\langle X^2\rangle-\langle X\rangle^2$ by setting $n=2$ and then subtracting off the square of the first-order moment $\langle X\rangle$. After obtaining $\langle X\rangle=m$ and $\mathrm{var}(X)=v$ in terms of $\mu$ and $\sigma$, we basically need to solve for $\mu$ and $\sigma$ from two equations

$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\ln m=\mu+\dfrac{\sigma^2}{2},\\
\ln(v+m^2)=2\mu+2\sigma^2.
\end{array}\right.\implies \quad\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\mu=\ln\left(
\dfrac{m}{\sqrt{1+v/m^2}}
\right)\!,\\
\sigma=\sqrt{\ln(1+v/m^2)}\,.
\end{array}\right.$$